# How to dynamically cast an object of type string to an object of type T

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have this XML document

```
<AdditionalParameters>
<PublishToPdf Type ="System.Boolean">False</PublishToPdf>
</AdditionalParameters>
```

in my code and I'm trying to build an array of arguments containing the `<PublishToPdf>` node.

```
object test = (object) ((typeof(publishNode.Attributes["Type"].value)) publishNode.InnerText);
```

This breaks at compile time of course. I can't figure out how to cast the `publishNode.InnerText('false')` to a runtime defined object of type specified in the XML file and store it in an object (which will conserve the type).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType` :

```
object value = Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, destinationType);
```

Comment: Yes, and to get destinationType, use 
var destinationType = Type.Parse(publishNode.Attributes["Type"].value);

Comment: Type.Parse() doesn't seem to exist. Did you mean Type.GetType() by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do exactly what you're trying to do. First, the `typeof` keyword does not allow for dynamic evaluation at runtime. There are means by which to do this using reflection, with methods like `Type.GetType(string)`, but the `Type` objects returned from these reflective functions can't be used for operations like casting.

What you need to do is provide a means of converting your type to and from a string representation. There is no automatic conversion from any arbitrary type. For your example, you can use `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse`, but those are specific to the `bool` type. There are similar methods on most primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution, assuming there is a limited number of possible types;

```
object GetValueObject(string type, string value)
{
  switch (type)
  {
    case "System.Boolean":
      return Boolean.Parse(value);
    case "System.Int32":
      return Int32.Parse(value);
    ...
    default:
      return value;
  }
}  

var type = publishNode.Attributes["Type"].value;
var value = publishNode.InnerText;
var valueObject = GetValueObject(type, value);
```

Comment: i'm working with .net framework 2.0. and i don't have var.
And the solution you suggested is the factory implementing the creation of objets of all types, which are countless.
But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Well, the var was just to make the code shorter, u can use string, string, object for these three instead. And, as I said, if you only need to support a limited number of types, this would work fine. If not, then you're right to say it's not practical.

Comment: With C# 6 you can use `case nameof(System.Guid):` for example. No need for const strings anymore. nameof is compile time generated.