# generic method to validate int, double. How to use GetType()?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a validation method. Eg: for double it looks like this:

```
   protected bool ValidateLoopAttributes(string i_value, double i_threshold)
       {
        double result;
        if (!(double.TryParse(i_value, out result) && result >= i_threshold))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is it possible to write this as:

```
     protected bool ValidateLoopAttributes<T>(string i_value, T i_threshold)
```

and then use something like

```
             T.GetType().TryParse() // how can i use here the type's methods??
```

Is using a switch/if statement the only way to do this? Eg:

```
    If (T.GetType() is int) 
        Int32.TryParse(i_threshold)
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Check Marc Gravell's answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654871/generic-tryparse-extension-method

Comment: `GetType()` is an instance method, so `T.GetType()` should not even compile. You need to use `typeof(T)`.

Comment: Why go to all of this trouble? If you're only worried about floats and integers, why not just have two overloads, `ValidateLoopAttributes(string i_value, double i_threshold)` and `ValidateLoopAttributes(string i_value, int i_threshold)` (or `long`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static class Ext
{
    public static bool TryParse<T>(string s, out T value)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        try
        {
            value = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static bool ValidateLoopAttributes<T>(string i_value, T i_threshold) 
           where T : IComparable
    {
        T outval;
        if (TryParse<T>(i_value, out outval))
            return outval.CompareTo(i_threshold) >= 0;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

My answer uses Marc Gravell's answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654871/generic-tryparse-extension-method).
With this you can do

```
bool b1 = Ext.ValidateLoopAttributes<int>("5", 4);
bool b2 = Ext.ValidateLoopAttributes<double>("5.4", 5.5d);
```

If you find it useful you can also use an extension method

```
public static bool ValidateLoopAttributes<T>(this string i_value, T i_threshold) 
       where T : IComparable { }
```

which leads you to use

```
bool b1 = "5".ValidateLoopAttributes<int>(4);
bool b2 = "5.4".ValidateLoopAttributes<double>(5.5d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool ValidateLoopAttributes<T>(string value, T threshold)
    where T : IComparable
{
    try
    {
        var parseMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new[] {typeof (string)});
        var result = (T) parseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {value});
        return result.CompareTo(threshold) < 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this only works for types with a static Parse method.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are mixing two things inside your method - parsing and business rules. Consider you invoke `ValidateLoopAttributes(value, 4)` and it returns `false`. Possible reasons:

1. String does not contain value. E.g. empty, some characters, etc.
2. String does not contain integer value. E.g. it has double value.
3. String contains integer value, but it exceeds threshold.
4. No converters defined for your type.

In first case you have invalid data in your source.
In second case you have invalid code, which should use double instead.
In third case code is OK, but business rule was broken.
In last case (which is not case for doubles or integers, but if you write generic code with no restrictions on type, you allow others to call it with any type) also problem in code.

So, think about separating business rules and parsing data.

```
Foo foo = Parse(xml);
RunBusinessRules(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try to use something like this to check if this is an integer or not:

```
public static bool IsNumericValue(string val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
{
    double result;
    return Double.TryParse(val,NumberStyle,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,out result);
}
```

so on

```
 IsNumericValue("1.2", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer) // FALSE
```

and on

```
 IsNumericValue("12", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer)  // TRUE
```

Pay attention that in *this* example I used `CurrectCulture`, fit it to *your* needs, if they are different.