# How to generalize a generic method to parse text and assign to a list of variables for different number of variables?

Tags: c#, .net, generic-programming

I need to read a tab (or comma) separated text and assign them to a list of built-in variables (int, char, string, etc. but not object). I want to handle this with a generic method. Here is the working code I am using for the case with three variables.

```
public static void ReadVariablesFromString<T0, T1, T2>(out T0 input0, out T1 input1, out T2 input2, string stringIn, char[] separators)
{
    string[] stringParts = stringIn.Split(separators);
    input0 = ConvertTo<T0>(stringParts[0]);
    input1 = ConvertTo<T1>(stringParts[1]);
    input2 = ConvertTo<T2>(stringParts[2]);
}

public static T ConvertTo<T>(object value)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

When I want to assign the tab separated text to three variables of different type, this is what I use:

```
string str = "a\t123\tbcd";

char var1;
int var2;
string var3;

char[] separators = { '\t' };

ReadVariablesFromString(out var1, out var2, out var3, str, separators);
```

Is there a way to generalize this model for different number of variables? Is it possible to write a generic method that accepts different number of variables for this specific case?

One of the other solution might be writing this method for a variable list with different types. Instead of passing variables one by one, is there a way to pass them in a list?

Answer (score 1):

No, in C# you can not send array of variable references.

But what you can do is create a class with some properties, and then use reflection to fill them.

See [Enumerating through an object's properties (string) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447308/enumerating-through-an-objects-properties-string-in-c-sharp) and [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)
and [How to dynamically cast an object of type string to an object of type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465855/how-to-dynamically-cast-an-object-of-type-string-to-an-object-of-type-t) on some details.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you return a List

`List<object> variables = ReadVariablesFromString(str, separators);`

Where each entry in the list will be the values your parse from the input string, for example

`variables.ElementAt(0) will be 'a'`

Since the type of the list is 'object', you can store any data type in there, since each type ultimately inherits from `object` anyway. You would need to cast the data when you need to use it though

`char letter = (char)variables.ElementAt(0)`

But you must be doing something similar already, otherwise how would you know which variable to put in each incoming `out` parameter.

Doing this means you have more flexibility in the amount of variables you can return from `ReadVariablesFromString()`